# DMA Init code for ADC sampled data

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, stm32f4, dma

I am trying to figure out how this DMA Initialization code is used to sample following 4 ADC channels and save data in 'adc_data'.

```
ADC1: channel 1 & channel 3.
ADC2: channel 2 & channel 4.
```

To me it looks like incomplete code as it is only initializing ADC1 but not ADC2. My MCU is STM32L476.

```
extern volatile uint32_t adc_data[];

  // DMA for ADC1
  RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA1EN; // DMA1
  // Wait a bit
  nop(); nop(); nop(); nop(); nop(); nop();
  DMA1_Channel1->CPAR = (uint32_t)&(ADC123_COMMON->CDR);
  DMA1_Channel1->CMAR = (uint32_t)&adc_data;
  DMA1_Channel1->CNDTR = 2;
  DMA1_Channel1->CCR = DMA_CCR_MSIZE_1 | DMA_CCR_PSIZE_1 | DMA_CCR_MINC |
                       DMA_CCR_CIRC | DMA_CCR_TCIE | DMA_CCR_EN;
```

Comment: It is incomplete code indeed. You need to see where `adc_data` is allocated. Somewhere someone must tell the linker what `adc_data` is and where it is allocated. This is one of many reasons why we should never do spaghetti programming with `extern`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup the ADC1 and ADC2 in a master-slave configuration. That will result in the samples of both ADCs being written to one common data register.

That data register is 32 bit wide, so transferring just 2 samples will actually contain the result of 4 conversions (2 from ADC1 and 2 from ADC2).

In the code to use the samples they should get extracted from the `adc_data[]` as they won't be useful as a single `uint32_t`.

For more information see the Reference Manual in Section 16.3.30 Dual ADC Modes.